# How did Trish's mom gain custody of Jessica?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, jessica-jones

During the series, we learn that Jessica's parents and brother were killed in a car accident that she somehow survived.  During her hospital visit, Trish and her mom visit her at the hospital and tell her that she's going to go live with them.

As far as I am aware, they aren't relatives at all.  How did Trish's mom gain custody of Jessica so quick?

Comment: How do we know it was quick? We know that she went to the hospital and *said* they would live together but we dont know how long that process actually took.

Comment: @Paulie_D if I remember correctly there's a scene of when she first comes to their home, and I believe it's implied that she just got out of the hospital.

Comment: Sure, but do we know how long she was there....and even then *temporary* custody is a thing.

Answer (score 1):

While those flashbacks are not exactly timestamped and thus we cannot realistically assume just how quick it was, I distinctly recall Trish or Dorothy saying something about this adoption being a publicity/P.R. stunt for Patsy. Good publicity tends to work wonders on the red tape, especially with a celebrity in the mix.